# node separating out mongo queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm looking at separating out my mongo db queries into a separate js file to help with reusing the code, something in the format below (this doesn't work). Any ideas how I could do this?

queries.js

```
var Merchants = require('../models/Merchants');

var query = {
  returnMerchantIDs: function () {
      var results = Merchants.find(function(err, merchants){
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            return merchants;
          })
        return results;
}

module.exports = query;
```

routes.js

```
var queries = require('../config/queries');

  app.get('/queries', function (req, res) {
    res.send(queries.returnMerchantIDs());
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'return merchants' is actually returning from the callback and not from the returnMerchantIDs function. That is the reason this is not working. There are 2 ways you could go about doing this.

Have returnMerchantIDs accept a callback like so

```
var query = {
  returnMerchantIDs: function (callback) {
      var results = Merchants.find(function(err, merchants){
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            callback(merchants);
          })
        return results;
}
```

and this is how you would call this

```
app.get('/queries', function (req, res) {
    queries.returnMerchantIDs(function(merchants) {
        res.send(merchants);
    }));
});
```

Or return the promise from mongoose to the caller and exec there passing the callback

```
var query = {
  returnMerchantIDs: function () {
      var results = Merchants.find();
        return results;
  }
}

app.get('/queries', function (req, res) {
    queries.returnMerchantIDs().exec(function(err, merchants)) {
        if (err) res.send(err) else res.send(merchants);
}
```